# Return value in delegate method but with completion hander

Tags: multithreading, return, return-value, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I have a map with the view controller as it's delegate, I call the below method to add some custom pins to the map and also get the route to them.

I want to add the distance of the route to the pins, so I need to calculate the route then add the distance to the custom pin before I return the pin.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
     //setup custom pin view and directions request

    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
    ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if (error) 
         {
              // error
         } else {
             // no error
         }
     }];

     // add distance to custom pin view
     // ONLY once directions calculated
     return custom pin view;
}
```

Any ideas how I would solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the view without waiting and then update it in your completion handler.  It's possible to synchronize an async call using `NSCondition` (and probably other ways) but when the main thread is being used for the completion, that's dangerous.